# set a value to a textbox which had focus in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, textinput

Hai guys,
    I have three textboxes and one listbox... If the user clicks the first textbox and then click a list item the selected item must be set as value to the textbox... I want this in javascript....

Comment: Is the selection mode set to multiple or single?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code for listbox with SelectionMode attribute set to Single.

```
var istBoxElement = document.getElementById ( "ListBox1" );
var textBoxElement = document.getElementById ( "txtBox1" );    

textBoxElement.value = elem.value;
```

and write this inside the onfocus event of the textbox element.

***Sample Code***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() { BindEvents(); }

    function BindEvents ()
    {
        var textBx = document.getElementById ( "txt1" );
        textBx.onfocus = function () {
            SetSel(this);
        }
    }

    function SetSel (elem)
    {
        alert ( elem.id );
        var elem = document.getElementById ( "ListBox1" );
        document.getElementById ( "txt1" ).value =  elem.value;
    }
</script>

<div id="divMain">
    <input type="text" id="txt1" />
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:ListBox>
</div>
```

Comment: how to get the Id of the textbox which had focus

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for onBlur. You can keep a variable with the last item viewed and just use JavaScript to set the text.

Comment: james i didnt get you.. some ex plz